# Concatenation overwrites in for loop

Tags: android, concatenation

I partially want to `concat` a string inside a `for` loop (inside a `while` loop). However, when it's concatenating inside the `for` loop, it's overwriting the past concatenating.
 I am quite new to programming, so I don't get why it's working fine outside a `for` loop and overwriting itself inside of it.

```
String uitslagtxt;
uitslagtxt = "Datum" + "|" + "Teamnamen" + "|" + "Uitslag" + "|" + "(Ruststand)"+"\n";

for (int i=0; i<1; i++){
    uitslagtxt = uitslagtxt.concat(row[1]+"|" +row[2]+"|"+row[3]+"|"+row[4].replace("\"","")+"\n");
    out.println("uitslagtxt in for loop: " + uitslagtxt);
}
```

So instead of giving 4 lines for example (which are all visible in the `out.println` check, see below),

```
Datum   |   Teamnamen   |   Uitslag   |   (Ruststand)    
1 jun. 2017     |  Thuis - Uit     |     2 - 2     |     (2 - 0)    
uitslagtxt in for loop: Datum  |   Teamnamen   |   Uitslag   |   (Ruststand)    
1 jun. 2017     |     Thuis - Uit     |     1 - 1     |     (1 - 0)    
uitslagtxt in for loop: Datum  |   Teamnamen   |   Uitslag   |   (Ruststand)   
1 jun. 2017     |     Thuis - Uit     |     3 - 3     |     (3 - 0)
```

it's only writing 2. How come?

```
Datum   |   Teamnamen   |   Uitslag   |   (Ruststand)   
1 jun. 2017     |     Thuis - Uit     |     3 - 3     |     (3 - 0)
```

Comment: what do you expect that `for (int i=0; i<1; i++){` to do?

Comment: Could you add the console output?

Comment: At the moment not much. This code is all inside a while loop, so it will execute multiple times (I edited my question).

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: Doesn't make a difference to the final output

Comment: Try now with new edit.

Comment: Suggestion: `out.printf` or StringBuilder class

Comment: @christianascone That did the trick! I didn't expect think that would have made the difference, but now I see it, it does. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suggest you to read some doc about variables scope. It's not the same for every language and it's necessary to understand it very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's overwriting the string because it is inside a while loop.
You declare the string inside while block, so every time it is repeated the variable is declared again.

Move the string declaration and initialization before starting the while loop.

```
String uitslagtxt;
uitslagtxt = "Datum" + "|" + "Teamnamen" + "|" + "Uitslag" + "|" + "(Ruststand)"+"\n"; 

while (condition) {
   // your code 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the += suggestion. The for loop is inside a while loop so it will execute multiple times and they are visible in the out.println check I did. But the previous result is overwritten every new excecution.

Comment: `concat` is a method of `String` that does exactly that, if you read the documentation